# Direct download Sql database azure portal data into excel sheet?

Tags: azure, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database, excel-2013

I want to download Azure Portal sql data into excel sheet without using sqlserver.
Is this Possible ? 
Data for security checks under Vulnerability Assessment (Preview),

See Sample Data :-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-vulnerability-assessment

Comment: The link you provided for the sample data returns a 404 error.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-vulnerability-assessment

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a SQL tool to download data from a SQL database into Excel. You have several options. The first one is to run a query in [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) and copy paste the result into Excel. Another option is to use the [bcp utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) with Unicode encoding (option -w).